# Very long response time, ends with error in almost cases

Tags: sharepoint-server

Good morning,
Yesterday i finished installing sp2013 server on my virtual machine (windows server 2008 R2 SP1).

When trying to launch the sp central administration, it takes very long time to show the authentication window. once authenticated, it also takes long time to (about 5 minutes) to show the central administration site OR an error message with "Something went wrong".

Have some any one an idea about how could be the reason of that.

Best Regards
ALI

Comment: What do the logs say when 'Something went wrong'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you do not have sufficient resource on your machine. What are the specifications of your virtual machine?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#hwforwebserver lists the requirement, although I think that the server will need more memory than just 8 GB if you have a couple of service applications, and search crawling. Probably around 10-12 for a somewhat smooth ride.